# Dynamic meta description

Tags: theme-development, headers

I am trying to make the `<meta name="description" content="">` pull the content from single posts, but I am running into a snag.

Currently I am using this:

`<meta name="description" content="<?php $post_id = the_ID(); $post = get_post($post_id); echo strip_tags(substr($post->post_content,0 , 150)); ?>">`

It works well but adds the post id in front of the content. Is there anyway to remove that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [the_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) function that you are using in your code echos the current post id, to get current post id instead of displaying it use the function [get_the_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) as shown in the following code.

Alternatively you can just use [get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function without passing any post id as a parameter because the post id parameter is optional and if you don't pass any post id then by default the current post is used.

Try using the following code instead of what you are using.

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php $post = get_post(get_the_ID()); echo strip_tags(substr($post->post_content,0 , 150)); ?>">
```